# Problema al detectar el tipo de clase usando herencia

Tags: java, poo, herencia

Estoy haciendo un pequeño ejercicio con herencia en Java, en el cual está la clase padre que es `Electrodomestico`, y de ahí heredan `Lavadora` y `Television`.

El problema que tengo es al sacar el total de cada uno de los electrodomésticos y el total en general. Por ejemplo, ingreso dos electrodomésticos de 200 cada uno, una lavadora de 400 y una televisión de 500; el total general es de 1300, en electrodomésticos hay 400, lavadora 400 y television 500. Eso es lo que tengo que hacer.

Estoy usando `instanceOf` para validar dentro del arreglo a qué clase pertenece cada objeto, el problema es que me sale el total general en electrodomésticos también, porque éste suma todos. Es decir le agrega el valor de lavadora y televisión también ya que son electrodomésticos, y no sé cómo hacer ahí para que esté el valor total de todos y el valor total de cada uno.

Aqui les dejo el código:

```
public class Electrodomestico {

    private static final String color_defecto = "blanco";
    private static final char consumo_electrico_defecto = 'F';
    private static final double precio_base_defecto = 100;
    private static final double peso_defecto = 5;
    private double precio_base;
    private String color;
    private char consumo_electrico;
    private double peso;
    private double valor_extra;

    public Electrodomestico () {

        this.color = color_defecto;
        this.consumo_electrico = consumo_electrico_defecto;
        this.precio_base = precio_base_defecto;
        this.peso = peso_defecto;

    }

    public Electrodomestico (double precio, double peso) {

        this.color = color_defecto;
        this.consumo_electrico = consumo_electrico_defecto;
        this.peso = peso;
        this.precio_base = precio;
        aumentarPrecio();
    }

    public Electrodomestico (String color, char consumo, double precio, double peso) {

        this.color = validarColor(color)?color:color_defecto;
        this.consumo_electrico = validarConsumo(consumo)?consumo:consumo_electrico_defecto;
        this.peso = peso;
        this.precio_base = precio;
        aumentarPrecio();
    }   

    public boolean validarConsumo(char consumo) {

        if (Character.toUpperCase(consumo) != 65 && Character.toUpperCase(consumo) 
                != 66 && Character.toUpperCase(consumo)  != 67 && Character.toUpperCase(consumo) 
                != 68 && Character.toUpperCase(consumo)  != 69 && Character.toUpperCase(consumo)  != 70) {
            return false;
        }else {
            return true;
        }   
    }

    public boolean validarColor(String color) {

        if (color.equalsIgnoreCase("azul") || color.equalsIgnoreCase("gris") || color.equalsIgnoreCase("negro") || color.equalsIgnoreCase("rojo")) {
            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }

    }

    public void aumentarPrecio() {

        if (this.peso >= 0 && this.peso <=19) {

            this.precio_base += 10;

        }else if (this.peso >= 20 && this.peso <=49) {

            this.precio_base += 50;

        }else if (this.peso >= 50 && this.peso <=79) {

            this.precio_base += 80;

        }else{

            this.precio_base += 100;

        }

        switch (Character.toUpperCase(this.consumo_electrico)) {

            case 65:
                this.precio_base += 100;
                break;
            case 66:
                this.precio_base += 80;
                break;
            case 67:
                this.precio_base += 60;
                break;
            case 68:
                this.precio_base += 50;
                break;
            case 69:
                this.precio_base += 30;
                break;
            case 70:
                this.precio_base += 10;
            break;
        }

    } public void agregar_al_Precio_base(double valor_extra) {

        this.precio_base += valor_extra;
    } //este metodo de agregar al precio base es por las clases hijas que si cumplen ciertas condiciones se le agregan valores extras al precio
}
```

Esa es la clase padre. Ahora las clases hijas:

```
public class Lavadora extends Electrodomestico{

    private static final int cargaDefecto = 5;
    private int carga;
    private int precio;

    public Lavadora() {

        super();
        this.carga = cargaDefecto;
    }

    public Lavadora(double precio, double peso) {

        super(precio, peso);
        this.carga = cargaDefecto;
        valoresExtras();
    }

    public Lavadora(String color, char consumo, double precio, double peso, int carga) {

        super(color, consumo, precio, peso);
        this.carga = carga;
        valoresExtras();
    }

    @Override
    public void valoresExtras() {

        if (this.carga > 30) {

            super.agregar_al_Precio_base(50);

        }
    }
}
```

Y Television:

```
public class Television extends Electrodomestico {

    private static final int pulgadas_defecto = 20;
    private static final boolean sintonizador_defecto = false;
    private double pulgadas;
    private boolean sintonizador;
    private double valor_extra;

    public Television() {

        super();
        this.pulgadas = pulgadas_defecto;
        this.sintonizador = sintonizador_defecto;
    }

    public Television(double precio, double peso) {

        super(precio, peso);
        this.pulgadas = pulgadas_defecto;
        this.sintonizador = sintonizador_defecto;
        valoresExtras();

    }



    public class Television extends Electrodomestico {

    private static final int pulgadas_defecto = 20;
    private static final boolean sintonizador_defecto = false;
    private double pulgadas;
    private boolean sintonizador;
    private double valor_extra;

    public Television() {

        super();
        this.pulgadas = pulgadas_defecto;
        this.sintonizador = sintonizador_defecto;
    }

    public Television(double precio, double peso) {

        super(precio, peso);
        this.pulgadas = pulgadas_defecto;
        this.sintonizador = sintonizador_defecto;
        valoresExtras();

    }

    public Television (String color, char consumo, double precio, double peso, double pulgadas, boolean sintonizador) {

        super(color, consumo, precio, peso);
        this.pulgadas = pulgadas;
        this.sintonizador = sintonizador;
        valoresExtras();
    }

    @Override
    public void valoresExtras() {

        if (this.pulgadas > 40 && this.sintonizador == true) {

            this.valor_extra = super.getPrecio_base();
            this.valor_extra = (this.valor_extra * 30 / 100) + 50;
            super.agregar_al_Precio_base(this.valor_extra);

        }else if (this.pulgadas > 40) {

            this.valor_extra = super.getPrecio_base();
            this.valor_extra = 50;
            super.agregar_al_Precio_base(this.valor_extra);

        }else if (this.sintonizador == true) {

            this.valor_extra = super.getPrecio_base();
            this.valor_extra = (this.valor_extra * 30 / 100);
            super.agregar_al_Precio_base(this.valor_extra);
        }

    }
```

Y ésta es la clase donde guarda todos los objetos y a lo último hace la operación:

```
public final class ArrayElectrodomesticos {

    private static ArrayList <Electrodomestico> ArrayElectrodomestico = new ArrayList <Electrodomestico> ();
    private static double total;
    private static double electrodomestico;
    private static double lavadora;
    private static double television;

    public static void agregarElectrodomesticos(Electrodomestico electrodomestico) {

        ArrayElectrodomestico.add(electrodomestico);

    }

    public static void mostrarInformacion() {

        //System.out.println("La sumatoria total de los electrodomesticos es de " + calcularTotal());
        calcularTotal();
        mostrarInformacionElectrodomesticos();
        /*System.out.println("El total de cada electrodomestico es de: ");
        System.out.println("Electrodomesticos: " + ArrayElectrodomesticos.electrodomestico);
        System.out.println("Lavadoras: " + ArrayElectrodomesticos.lavadora);
        System.out.println("Televisores: " + ArrayElectrodomesticos.television);*/
    }

    public static void calcularTotal() {

        for (int i = 0; i < ArrayElectrodomestico.size() ; i++) {

            ArrayElectrodomesticos.total += ArrayElectrodomestico.get(i).getPrecio_base();
        }

    }

    public static void mostrarInformacionElectrodomesticos() {

        for (int i = 0; i < ArrayElectrodomestico.size() ; i++) {

            if (ArrayElectrodomestico.get(i) instanceof Lavadora) {

                System.out.println(ArrayElectrodomestico.get(i).getPrecio_base());
            }
            if (ArrayElectrodomestico.get(i) instanceof Electrodomestico) {

                System.out.println(ArrayElectrodomestico.get(i).getPrecio_base());

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: El problema es que nunca has agregado "200 o 300 televisores" siempre le has ido añadiendo a electrodomésticos, tendrás que tener en cada clase, televisión, lavadora sus correspondientes totales, sino nunca podrás saber cuantas teles y lavadoras hay por separado.

Comment: En método `calcularTotal` no identifica diferencias entre tus objetos, suma todo lo que está en tu array.

Comment: ese es para el total en general, el metodo encargado de la suma de cada uno por separado esta abajo, mostrarinformacionElectrodomestico

Answer (score 0):

El problema principal con el código es que no está diferenciando qué electrodomésticos son diferentes al calcular el total, suma los precios de todos.

Esta parece una pregunta de tarea por lo que no daré una solución directa.

Trataré de explicar con un ejemplo diferente como puedes usar `instanceof` para identificar cual es la clase y con eso calcular el total.

Dado este código:

```
package co.rooam.bi.rabbitmq.consumer.enricher;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class ElectrodomesticosMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Electrodomestico> electrodomesticos = Arrays.asList(
                new Lavadora().conPrecio(100.00),
                new Lavadora().conPrecio(110.00),
                new Television().conPrecio(200.00),
                new Television().conPrecio(210.00)
        );

        double total = electrodomesticos.stream()
                .mapToDouble(Electrodomestico::getPrecio)
                .sum();

        System.out.println("El total es de " + total);

        double totalTelevisiones = electrodomesticos.stream()
                .filter((Electrodomestico e) -> e instanceof Television)
                .mapToDouble(Electrodomestico::getPrecio)
                .sum();

        System.out.println("El total para los televisores es de " + totalTelevisiones);

        double totalLavadoras = electrodomesticos.stream()
                .filter((Electrodomestico e) -> e instanceof Lavadora)
                .mapToDouble(Electrodomestico::getPrecio)
                .sum();

        System.out.println("El total para las lavadoras es de " + totalLavadoras);
    }

    public static abstract class Electrodomestico {
        private double precio;

        public double getPrecio() {
            return precio;
        }

        public void setPrecio(double precio) {
            this.precio = precio;
        }

        public Electrodomestico conPrecio(double precio) {
            this.precio = precio;
            return this;
        }
    }

    public static class Lavadora extends Electrodomestico {
    }

    public static class Television extends Electrodomestico {
    }
}
```

Hay tres clases, `Lavadora` y `Television` son las clases hijas de `Electrodomestico`. La primer linea de `main` crea una lista de `Electrodomesticos` que contiene dos instancias de `Lavadora` y dos instancias de `Television`.

Para tener el precio total de lavadoras de esa lista hay que identificar solo las que son lavadoras, eso se logra con `.filter((Electrodomestico e) -> e instanceof Lavadoras)` (está usando una [expresión lambda](https://www.ecodeup.com/entendiendo-paso-a-paso-las-expresiones-lambda-en-java/) para filtrar solo las lavadoras).

Lo que nos interesa no son las lavadoras como tal sino el precio de estas, para obtener los precios usa `.mapToDouble(Electrodomestico::getPrecio)` (usa un [método referenciado](https://www.oscarblancarteblog.com/2017/02/27/java-8-metodos-referenciados/) para obtener el precio) y finalmente los suma con `.sum()`. Lo mismo aplica para el total de los televisores.

Mismo ejemplo, pero sin usar `streams`:

```
package co.rooam.bi.rabbitmq.consumer.enricher;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class ElectrodomesticosMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Electrodomestico> electrodomesticos = Arrays.asList(
                new Lavadora().conPrecio(100.00),
                new Lavadora().conPrecio(110.00),
                new Television().conPrecio(200.00),
                new Television().conPrecio(210.00)
        );

        double total = 0;
        double totalTelevisiones = 0;
        double totalLavadoras = 0;

        for (Electrodomestico electrodomestico : electrodomesticos) {

            if (electrodomestico instanceof Lavadora) {
                totalLavadoras += electrodomestico.precio;
            }

            if (electrodomestico instanceof Television) {
                totalTelevisiones += electrodomestico.precio;
            }

            total += electrodomestico.precio;
        }

        System.out.println("El total es de " + total);
        System.out.println("El total para los televisores es de " + totalTelevisiones);
        System.out.println("El total para las lavadoras es de " + totalLavadoras);
    }

    public static abstract class Electrodomestico {
        private double precio;

        public double getPrecio() {
            return precio;
        }

        public Electrodomestico conPrecio(double precio) {
            this.precio = precio;
            return this;
        }
    }

    public static class Lavadora extends Electrodomestico {
    }

    public static class Television extends Electrodomestico {
    }
}
```

Ambos dan la siguiente salida:

```
> Task :ElectrodomesticosMain.main()
El total es de 620.0
El total para los televisores es de 410.0
El total para las lavadoras es de 210.0
```

Comment: brutal, pero lo hice y aun asi no los separa xD